# Amount of X day increments from date

Tags: macos, bash, date

I need to find, in OSX (I mention this since `date` has different options from most Linux distros), how many increments of X days have passed since a certain date.

Let’s say the date is July 31, 2013, and I need to find how many 10 day increments have passed. Running the command today (August 29, 2013) — the result would be `2`, and tomorrow (August 30, 2013), the result would be `3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @konsolebox’s answer, here’s how to do it on OSX (see his answer for a working solution on Linux).

```
echo "$(( ($(date '+%s') - $(date -j -f '%Y-%m-%d' '2013-07-31' '+%s')) / (10 * 24 * 3600) ))"
```

or (broken down)

```
now=$(date '+%s')
other=$(date -j -f '%Y-%m-%d' '2013-07-31' '+%s')
echo "$(( (now - other) / (10 * 24 * 3600) ))"
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the timestamps then calculate it:

```
echo "$(( ($(date -d 'now' '+%s') - $(date -d 'July 31, 2013' '+%s')) / (10 * 24 * 3600) ))"
```

More readable form:

```
now=$(date -d 'now' '+%s')
other=$(date -d 'July 31, 2013' '+%s')
echo "$(( (now - other) / (10 * 24 * 3600) ))"
```

Timestamps are in seconds since epoch (1970-01-01 UTC).

Comment: +1 nice.  I was looking for a way of supplying `date` with a more machine-readable format (i.e. `date -d 073100002012 +%s`) but it doesn't seem possible.  It might be cumbersome to generate `July 31, 2013`.

Comment: `-d` doesn’t work like that in OSX (it sets the kernel’s value for daylight saving time), so this does not work.

Comment: @user137369 Looks like the other guys disapproved the edit sorry. But it's ok :)

Comment: @konsolebox Well, at least we have two answers now, so either coming from Linux or OSX, people will have an answer. Thank you for providing the base for the solution I needed.